# How To Traverse The One Imagelist Images with other ImageList Images

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]
Thanks In Advance Friends Can you tell me how to traverse one Image list images with Second Image list and it will be saved in folder by appending first Image list image to second Image list Images Names...Each First Image List Image must be Append its name by second Image List with All the Images...

Comment: Very abstract... Any code you have made?

Comment: Yeah but code is doing that it takes images in Imagelists..

Comment: I mean, do you have something like `List<Image> imageList1` or anything sort?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of nested `for` loops?

Comment: No Ian I have no List<Image> imagelist1

Comment: no it dose not matter for loop i know that Loop will be used but how I dont know nikhilvartak

Comment: Why don't you share the code you're talking about, then we can see where it is doing wrong

Comment: @RumeelHussain you may consider to create one then... It might be what you need